# Fatal error in PHP function prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using prepared statement for login. The compiler is giving a fatal error in the store result function. It is not saving the row in the result that I want to show. I saw solutions but they are not working.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login where email=? and password=?";
    $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["email"],$_POST["password"]);
    $stmt->execute();

    //$res=$result->num_rows;
    $res=store_result();
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {

        // output data of each row

      while($row['admin_role']==1)
      {
        $_SESSION["email"]=$email;
        $_SESSION["id"]=$row['user_id'];
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit; 
      }
     } else {
       echo "0 results";
     }
 }

?>
```

Comment: What is the fatal error exactly as I expect that will be your answer?

Comment: $res=store_result(); this

Comment: Thats not an error, thats a variable assignment...

Comment: so how do i show that $row['admin_role']==1, it is giving fatal error.

Comment: Again, what is the fatal error? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: : Call to undefined function store_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cablewala\login.php

Comment: So as suspected there is your issue - store_result() is not a function name

Comment: yes but now it is expecting a parameter?

Comment: Yes, again as per the docs - why not provide it one then? Or does calling $conn->store_result() work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148725/discussion-between-tariq-ziad-and-peter-featherstone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.store-result.php) and the error message you are getting the function name should be `mysqli_store_result` and not `store_result`.

You will also need to provide your connection variable which looking at your code above appears to be `$conn` so it would be:

```
mysqli_store_result($conn)
```

Alternatively I believe you could call it as a class method directly using your `$conn` variable as below:

```
$conn->store_result()
```